# How to fix SQL injection if we have to use DB name dynamically in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-injection

This is the implementation in code: the schema name comes from a configuration file and is different for each environment. Sonar throws SQL injection alert at this statement:

```
select * 
from dbName.dbo.stu_name;     <<dbname is the variable that comes from property file>>
```

I tried these solutions:

1. Using `query.setParameter(?,dbname)`. Tried passing dbname dynamically and vulnerability was fixed. When debugging, the query was throwing an error and did not execute.
2. Used `String.format(select * from \'%s\',tablename.replace("\'","\'\'"))` - vulnerability fixed, but query failed to execute

I tried various other solutions and nothing worked.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You should post some code and specify which technology you're using. And use a print to see the actual query you're getting

Comment: You **cannot** parametrize database object names - like tables, columns etc. - only values. If you really must do this - again, really?!?! - then you must resort to using **dynamic SQL** (which has its own share of tricky drawbacks and issues)

Comment: You can *limit* the avenue of attack by validating the database name, and then using `QUOTENAME` to properly quote it.

Comment: Wait, is the table ***and*** database name dynamic..?

Comment: @ThomA : Database name is dynamic and table name is the same for all envs.

Comment: Why does your title say the table is dynamic then?

Comment: @siggemannen : We use Java8 and retrieve the results after executing the query.We use Hibernate as ORM tool

Comment: Query, never heard of it, is that built-in or some ORM?

Comment: @ThomA: Sorry for the confusion.Edited the question.

Comment: What is your Java SDK version?  Check it out Java's **String Templates**  functionality here: https://openjdk.org/jeps/430

Answer (score 1):

The "best" defence you can do is *not* use dynamic SQL. Considering that this is the database that's dynamic, and based on a prior question, I would *suggest* that this is occurring from an application, so that means you *don't* need 3-part naming. Instead you parametrise the database name in the connection string and use 2-part naming; no dynamic SQL needed.

If you *must* use dynamic SQL, then the "best™️" defence would be to validate the database name, and then ensure you properly quote the database name when you inject it into your dynamic statement.

Here I validate the database name in `sys.databases` and then use `QUOTENAME` to quote the name appropriately. If the database doesn't exist, no query is run (and no error is returned):

```sql
DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname = N'YourDatabaseName';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.stu_name;'
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.name = @DatabaseName;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Thom's advice about validating the database name, to avoid injecting the database name in the query, you can just execute the dynamic SQL in the context of that database. If somehow `@DatabaseName` had some garbage in it from a user, it would just not work.

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.stu_name;';

DECLARE @exec nvarchar(1024),
  @db sysname = QUOTENAME(DB_NAME(DB_ID(@DatabaseName)));          

IF @db IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @exec = @db + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

  EXEC @exec @sql;
END
```

I wrap it in `DB_NAME(DB_ID(` to avoid complications with names passed in *already quoted* with `[]` or `""`.

Another benefit of this approach - aside from not putting potentially dangerous user input directly into a query you execute - is that functions like `OBJECT_ID()` and `DB_NAME()` work, because they run in that database's context.

Comment: I like this solution, as there's no actual injection; it's a method I too often forget about. Plus, even *if* you didn't bother validating the database name, it won't cause problems. `DECLARE @Procedure nvarchar(514) = N'[SELECT * FROM sys.databases]' + N'.sys.sp_executesql'; EXEC @Procedure N'SELECT * FROM sys.tables';` will just generate the error *"Database 'SELECT * FROM sys.databases' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly."*